# How to make Graph like below image in angular

Tags: json, angular, api, graph, linechart

As I am New To Angular i am facing issue in Graph , I don't now how to make this in angular

Tried with Chart.js and Canvasjs In both i am facing problem
1. With Chart.js i was able to create static graph like below image, but i am not getting how to get data from API for this graph.

Note: I am Able to display any kind of data Using API , except Graph  So, Please Help me with this Graph thing.

[image]

```
LineChart = {};

  ngOnInit() {
    // Line chart:
    this.LineChart = new Chart('lineChart', {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Number of Items Sold in Months',
          data: [9, 7, 3, 5, 2, 10, 15, 16, 19, 3, 1, 9],
          fill: false,
          lineTension: 0.2,
          borderColor: 'white',
          borderWidth: 1
        }]
      },
      options: {
        title: {
          text: 'Line Chart',
          display: true
        },
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    });
```

Note: I am Able to display any kind of data Using API , except Graph  So, Please Help me with this Graph thing.

Graph should Come

Comment: check this library with chart.js https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/ . It will help you

Comment: Sheif,  i gone through this library but its not telling that how to display data through API.

Comment: I never used chartjs so it is maybe irrelevant. Have you tried to create a variable getting the data from you API and use it in your chart data? something like `this.LineChart.data.labels = myAPILabelArray` and `this.LineChart.data.datasets[0].data = MyAPIDataArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Initialising the Chart Object, fetch the data from the API and create the data array, then initialise the Chart Object.

If you want the graph to be continually changing, use Observables to get the data continuously and keep updating the charts.